# trouble with fscanf() in matlab

Tags: matlab, scanf

I have a data file that was written in Fortran (?) with a format F7.3, so the rows look like this

```
78.225  0.053 78.230  0.068 78.235  0.079 78.240  0.079 78.245  0.071
78.250  0.047 78.255  0.017 78.260 -0.019 78.265 -0.039 78.270 -0.042
...
```

which is nice, but as the numbers get bigger they start looking like

```
195.950  0.001195.955  0.001195.960  0.002195.965  0.002195.970  0.002
195.975  0.003195.980  0.003195.985  0.004195.990  0.004195.995  0.004
...
```

which is not convenient. I'm planning to do some calculations with this data, but now I can't even save it as a vector. I have tried

```
FID=fopen(file);
data=fscanf(FID, '%f');
```

which almost does the job, with the detail that for big numbers it stores them incorrectly, for example the last line is stored as

```
195.9750
0.0032
0.9800
0.0032
0.9850
0.0042
0.9900
0.0042
0.9950
0.0040
```

when they should be stored as

```
195.975
0.003
195.9800
0.003
195.9850
0.004
195.9900
0.004
195.9950
0.004
```

I don't really know how to tell MATLAB to scan the file in the correct way. I have tried

```
data=fscanf(FID, '%7.3f'); % (and '%f7.3')
```

with no success. It is kind of the first time I encounter this problem, guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delimiter is missing, any formatted parsing will probably fail. Due to the regular shape of the text file, I would use reshape:

```
charspercolumn=7
fid = fopen('filename');

tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    x=str2num(reshape(tline',charspercolum,[])')
    %store your data somewhere
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end    
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: thanks, that works (just changed num2str to str2num).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to create the data file with spaces as delimiters, and then your matlab code will contain a simple, readable, fscanf statement.

This change might involve modifying a format statement in Fortran program?

Comment: I can't create the data again, I have to use that file in that format.

Comment: Ariaramnes, try writing a C program that reads the file byte-by-byte (i.e. parses it) and reformats it into something that can be read by Matlab's fscanf.  Or, use a Fortran program, which will understand the file's format, and create a file with space delimiters on each field.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I wanted to be able to use the file directly in Matlab.

Comment: Ariaramnes, Why?  if the point is to get the job done, then make your life easy.  If you are trying to learn Matlab by setting difficult, if not impossible goals, then good luck, but don't ask me to do your learning for you!!

Comment: I would love to do it with C (my favourite language) but sadly I'm required by other engineers/people to use Matlab and the file just as it is. :(. Sorry :(.

Comment: Ariaramnes, not a problem.  If this is a work-place question then meet the requirements (obviously).  However, always remember the Kobyashi-Maroo test (i.e. star trek); and look for the easiest path forward.